# Weird raster visualisation

Tags: raster, srtm, hillshade

Using the hillshade tool (ArcMap 10) on a 30m SRTM raster downloaded from NED the result is the one in the picture. Why are there those crossed lines all over the raster? How could I remove them?

[image]

Comment: Related question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18516/is-hillshade-option-in-arcmap-rubbish-or-is-it-me

Answer (score 7):

A few thoughts:

- A [previous answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/18523/8104) correctly recommends resampling during display
  to smooth out the irregularities in the hillshade.  This is primarily
  used for cartographic effect when you are finishing a map.

[image]

- Use the [Image Analysis window](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t000001tm000000) to run a 5x5 smoothing window over
  the image

[image]

- Find better elevation data.  10 m NED Data is available for the
  conterminous USA and 3m is available in select areas.  I like to
  download NED data from the [National Map](http://viewer.nationalmap.gov/viewer/)

[image]

- Finally, to put everything together, consider using advanced overlay
  methods in Image Analyst, rather than using washed out transparent
  overlays.  Here is a great blog that describes these [techniques](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/03/08/an-alternative-to-overlaying-layer-tints-on-hillshades/).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
I tried the first three methods. The first one does not seem to work on my case, since it just seems to decrease slightly the appearance of those crossed lines. For what concerns the Image Analysis window I can open it but all the tools under "display" and "processing" are unselectable, why?
And is the national map downloading site openable outside USA? (I'm in Italy). Because it does not load the page.
Thank you again, Michele.

Comment: Sorry I was then able to select the smoothing option. It made it better though didn't clean it completely.

Comment: Make sure to highlight and check the image in the top window, then all of the processing tools should become available.  The National Map is available for USA data, although I do not know if there is any download restrictions out of the country.  It looks like Italy has a 10m DEM dataset available: http://tinitaly.pi.ingv.it/download.html.

Comment: I should also add that you can make multiple passes too with any of the processing tools.

Comment: The place of which I need the DEM is in California and the best my supervisors were able to send me is a 30m SRTM

Comment: If you cannot access the National Map, try downloading 10m DEMs at GIS Data Depot: http://data.geocomm.com/