# How to add hillshades to a raster map?

Tags: hillshade

I have a raster map **without** hillshades and want to **add Hillshades** derived from the SRTM90 dataset. 
I am looking for a tool, that can handle that **as automatic as possible**?
I don't want to bother with too much with Data-Download, -Conversion and -Processing. I am looking for a tool, that can be handled by an end-user!

Comment: What software and version are you using? ArcGIS 10.2, QGIS, etc.

Answer (score 2):

for automatisation of process I am not sure, but here you can find something about utilisation and combination of DEM and classified raster to obtain nice map: [Using Hillshade option in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18516/is-hillshade-option-in-arcmap-rubbish-or-is-it-me/18523#18523).

Breefly, to add hillshades on your raster, you need to display:

1. your raster (n°1)
2. DEM raster  (display as bilinear interpolation)

and then **set your raster transparency** (raster n1°) in Layer properties on 85% (or your value)[image]